# Linearlayout not displaying anything

Tags: android, android-layout

I using android:layout_weight to limit the size of my view but now I'm not seeing anything on the screen. Here are the codes:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="2" 
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
   <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                             android:layout_weight="3" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
               >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way hope this will help you...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0.25 % Area"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.75 % Area"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="100dp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="2" 
                android:orientation="vertical"/>
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                     <LinearLayout 
                         android:layout_width="50dp" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         android:layout_weight="3" 
                         android:orientation="vertical"
                      >
```

This will help you to see something. Change the width according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

try this, first u need to give the weight sum in main linear layout.
Also change 0dp to 0 dip

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5">

<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="2" 
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         android:layout_weight="3" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **weightSum** property in your parent Linear layout, like **android:weightSum="number of child"**

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:weightSum="5">

<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="2" 
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" 
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:orientation="vertical"
       >
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:layout_width="0dp"` will make this layout invisible. Change it to `wrap_content` or something else.